# How to ensure that JMS messages read within a rolled back session are processed after never-before-read messages?

Tags: java, transactions, jms, priority-queue

I am going to use a Session to commit the read of a JMS message after it (and any corresponding write) has successfully completed.

However, if I have an error, and have to do a rollback, I would like to process new messages first, rather than the one that had (caused???) the error that had to be rolled back.  I want to eventually reprocess the failed message, but not to fail over and over while other yet-unseen messages stall behind it, waiting for action to remove the offending message or fix the environment that made it fail.

Is this automatic?  (will be using Sonic MQ, if that matters).  If so, the rest of this question is moot.

Do I need to, or can I even, reset the priority of the failed message to push it further back in the queue (behind other pending messages, if any)?  If I need to reset the priority, how do I make that "stick", given that I would have rolled back the transaction that initially read the message in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of feature in Sonic MQ which supports your requirements out-of-the-box, but there are other options:

- Use a second queue for failed messages. So failed messages are sent again on another queue. Processing could start, if the first queue is empty, for example.
- Resend the message on the same queue (with same or even with a lower priority)

In both cases, after the message has been sent, there is a normal `commit` on the main queue.

Related: [Message processing with priorities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/387471/2390083). A quote from James Shek's answer:

> JMS Spec states: "JMS does not require that a provider strictly implement priority ordering of messages; however, it should do its best to deliver expedited messages ahead of normal messages."